# Pin out for Bosch ignition coil (Part No# 12131712219)?

Tags: engine, ignition-coil

Does anyone have any information on this particular Bosch ignition coil for BMW. The part no. is 12131712219. Tried googling it but was couldn't find much info. I would be really grateful if anyone here can help me out.

Update: I found a picture of another brand that claims to be a similar replacement for the Bosch. But I'm confused with below picture if these are th same. Especially the top pin.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should provide this information as an answer to highlight the correct pin-out obtained from Bosch for any future members who wish to do a rewiring or troubleshooting.

I wanted to give an update to this answer. I didn't go ahead with the wiring mentioned in this post as I wasn't fully confident if that is the right one. Also I was concerned that it might damage my ECU if I wired it wrong especially since this has high voltage present.

I had contacted the Bosch Global team but they could only get me a catalog and other data for the coil, nothing related to pinout. Next tried contacting the Bosch USA but they just directed be to their Bosch India Auto parts, yet to hear back from them after to weeks. Finally I contacted their Middle East team  who told me they would contact the engineering team and get back with the pin-out. After a week finally they have provided. **Here is the correct pin-out from Bosch**:

[image: **Pin-out assignment**]

Answer (score 2):

This is a beautiful diagram for the ignition coil pinouts.
[image]

Comment: After some deeper digging I found another brand coil which says its a replacement to the Bosch coil pack I had mentioned. I've attached a picture of the connection I found. It seems to have a resistance details and the pinout. But it's little different from the one you have posted. The "Signal" pin here is "Ground"

Comment: Yeah that schematic is spot on. I may have mislabeled them as I didn't know their function but the coloring matched. I based the diagram off of photos of coil pack harnesses and the brown wires did all get bunched up and seems to me that they were bolted to the chassis. 'Signal' should be the chassis ground and 'ground' should be the circuit ground

Comment: So, the Brown Signal wire was connected to the chassis? Okay. So in that case it should show high resistance I'm assuming as the brown wire and the internal spark plug connection could be the high voltage output it seems like.